# metodo put con ajax en nodejs-express

Tags: jquery, ajax, nodejs, express

Tengo el siguiente esquema en node js

```
router.put('/records/update/:cod_history', async(req,res)=>{
const records = await Records.findOneAndUpdate({cod_history:req.params.cod_history},
{ status: true },
{ new: true }
);
res.json('Actualizado');});
```

Cuando hago la prueba en postman me funciona y normal puedo cambiar el "status" que por defecto lo inserto en "false" a "true", pero al hacer mi peticion en ajax de tipo PUT no me funciona o quiza este haciendo algo mal, tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
$('table').on('click','.return-button',function(){
let row = $(this).closest('tr');
let cod_history = row.find('.cod_history').text();//aqui obtengo el codigo de cada "tr"

$.ajax({
  url: '/records/update/' + cod_history,
  type: 'PUT',
  success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
});});
```

Comment: Me parece que estas haciendo el put a la misma url donde sirves el sitio, no donde está el api. Tienes que usar la url completa del api en la llamada ajax.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, creo que por entender eso debo empezar, puedes explicarme un poco mejor? por favor

Comment: Al parecer no estas senalando a ninguna pagina. Como comenta @devconcept debes de poner la url completa en esta linea `router.put('/records/update/:cod_history' ... `. Deberia ser algo como `router.put('192.168.1.XX:3000/records/update/:cod_history' ...`

Comment: Ya complete tambien la url completa y aun asi no me funciona, o la estructura de mi ajax esta mal

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL que usas en postman?